# spring batch -dynamic csv reader with varying column

Tags: java, spring, logic, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to process a CSV file.

## sample.csv

```
 fullname,dateOfBirth,  gender, nationality
 Joe Smith,09/11/1966, M, America
 William Norman,22/22/1988,M, Cuba
```

## changed_csv.csv

```
 fullname,dateOfBirth,  gender, nationality,currency,regions
 Joe Smith,09/11/1966, M, America,Dollar, North America
 William Norman,22/22/1988,M, Cuba,Peso, South America
```

## My Reader

```
enter code here .   


 private FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader(String filename) {
        FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        reader.setStrict(false);
        log.debug("Job parameter {}", filename);
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filename));
        reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
        reader.setLineMapper(new PersonLineMapper());
        return reader;
    }
enter code here .   
public PersonLineMapper() {
    super();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    lineTokenizer.setNames(  "fullname","dateOfBirth",  "gender", "natinlaity");
    setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    beanWrapperFieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Person.class);
    beanWrapperFieldSetMapper.setCustomEditors(Collections.singletonMap("java.time.LocalDate", new LocalDatePropertyEditor()));
    setFieldSetMapper(beanWrapperFieldSetMapper);
}
```

Everything works fine.

My question is  is there a way to dynamically map, the csv to the bean .
Like my csv has new header introduced , how to process them

Comment: you mean to say argument to `reader.setLinesToSkip(1);` becomes to `2` from `1` ?

Comment: I use the below solution

Comment: Got any Solution for this?